# Toastr JS keep toasts visible indefinitely

Tags: javascript, toastr

I'm attempting to show a toast message using the Toastr plugin from John Papa. (http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html)
I'm having trouble finding an option to have the toasts remain on screen indefinitely without manually setting the "timeOut" and "extendedTimeOut" values to something absurdly high. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

```
toastr.options = {
    "closeButton": true,
    "timeOut": "500000",
    "extendedTimeOut": "100000"
}
toastr.error('Error!');
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Based on the [code](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr/blob/8bbd8db7a8dd4f8e6ddcbca2acf4a2e88aab86f4/nuget/content/scripts/toastr.js#L175), set them to 0

```
timeOut: 5000, // Set timeOut and extendedTimeout to 0 to make it sticky
```

Comment: In addition I had to set "extendedTimeOut": 0 as well.

Comment: This worked for me with bootstrap 4 but with bootstrap 5, the options don't work properly. I set 0 for timeOut and for extendedTimeOut, but the toast still closes after a short-while.

Comment: You confirmed that it also works with version 5 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75242712/toastr-options-not-working-with-bootstrap-5

Answer (score 2):

To display toast until user closes, set disableTimeOut and closeButton

```
        toastr.error("Message", "Title", { disableTimeOut: true, closeButton:true });
```

Comment: Does this work if bootstrap 5 is also used ?