# toastr options not working with bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, toastr

I have a web app that uses bootstrap and [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr).
I recently upgraded the bootstrap library from bootstrap4 to bootstrap5.
I then found out that toastr options do not work properly.
For example the toastr.options timeOut, extendedTimeOut don't respond to their new values.
The toast is raised for a short duration, regardles the values that I set for `toastr.options.timeout`.

The call to the toastr is:

```
let toastrSettings = { 
    timeOut: 5000,
    extendedTimeOut: 5000
};

toastr.error('Some message', 'Some Title', toastrSettings);
```

Could it be that toastr (toastr/2.1.4/toastr.min.js) does not work with bootstrap 5?

Alternatively I see bootstrap [toasts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/toasts/) and [alerts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/alerts/).
But there it looks like the toast is set into the DOM.
If toastr does not work with bootstrap 5, I'm looking or a library that provides the option to set dynamically the title and content, similarly to toastr.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mistakenly thought that adding bootstrap 5.x.x caused the problem.
But the root cause was that a bit later in the code after raising the toast I had:
`toastr.clear();`
which caused the toast to disappear regardless of the extended timeout.
So my conclusion is that bootstrap 5.x.x and toastr can coexist.